# Azure Devops self-hosted agent with docker

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have installed an Azure self hosted agent (Linux) and am following the documentation  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops.

I have succeeded in installing the agent however when I run a Docker Build task which compiles and builds a docker image I am getting an error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

After googling the issue it seems the code below should mount the docker.sock and I should be able to build and push docker images successfully, however this did not work on AKS

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-volume
      volumes:
      - name: docker-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Has anyone encountered any such issue? I am building using AzureDevops `Docker@2` task and agent is running on AKS `1.19.11`

Answer (score 1):

Since AKS 1.19 it uses containerd as the container runtime - which means that you cannot directly build docker images inside AKS anymore. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#containerd-limitationsdifferences) article for details and possible workarounds.

In general, I find [VMSS-based self-hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops) for Azure DevOps a great alternative to container-based agents.